Spring cant see lombok constructors
When I'm trying to run my application I get an error:
java: variable userRepository not initialized in the default constructor
Here is the config file in which the problem occurs (as it turned out, the problem is with all the annotations that the constructors create)
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return email -> userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User haven't found"));
    }
...

UserRepository:
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

}


"Enable annotation processing" is turning on
already tried invalidate cashes
tried reinstall lombok plugin


Do you get this error in runtime or when compiling?

while compiling

Are you sure this problem is from Lombok. I mean if you define a constructor for AppConfig and initialize UserRepository there, problem will fix?

Yes, when I write constructors by myself the error disappears

Try adding annotation processor path in your assembly file (as pom.xml) at
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>{maven.compile.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <path>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


There are already two :(
One that you just sent and one:

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-maven-plugin



org.projectlombok
lombok





Don't do things like that in an @Configuration class. Instead just wire the dependency into the @Bean method.
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return email -> userRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User haven't found"));
    }
}

This makes it even easier for Spring to determine dependencies and do the wiring. Next to that it saves you from Lombok (I have a love/hate relationship with Lombok, more hate then love :) ).
